pandas dataframe filter rows by datetime
I have a dataframe with (non index) column called 'est'.  I want to filter out rows having datetime prior to 2023-01-01.  I tried as below
spot = df.query(df.est >= date(year=2023, month=1, day=1))
spot = df[df['est'].dt >= date(year=2023, month=1, day=1)]

but its throwing error as ValueError: expr must be a string to be evaluated, <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> given or AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. Did you mean: 'at'?.
est column is created from column 't' --where t is having UTC unix timestamp in miliseconds (1/1000) like 1656662400000, 1656668700000. and est column is created with code below
df["est"] = pd.to_datetime(df["t"], unit="ms")
df["est"] = df["est"].dt.tz_localize("UTC").dt.tz_convert("US/Eastern").dt.date

I tried few other things but failed, searched online but most of result is showing using .loc after indexing the column.  How can I filter data without indexing the column?  Thanks!

Just use boolean indexing and read up on Indexing and selecting data.
import pandas as pd

# sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'est': pd.date_range('2024-01-01', '2024-01-31')})
# filter dates greater than 2024-01-10
df[df['est'].gt('2024-01-10')]

Make sure you data is datetime first
df['est'] = pd.to_datetime(df['est'])
